# Null fields in POJO with application/json and BeanParam

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, json-deserialization

I have a REST service operation defined in a controller class, as shown:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("create")
public Response createWidget(@BeanParam Widget widget) {
    ...
}
```

Widget is a POJO bean class, i.e. 2 private fields named `foo` & `bar` of type `String` with public getters & setters, and a public no-arg constructor.

The POST request body is:

```
{ "foo": "Some text", "bar": "Some more text" }
```

and has header `Content-Type: application/json`

On firing this request, the `createWidget` method gets a `Widget` object as argument but both `String` fields are `null`.

Can someone tell me what else is needed for the fields to be populated? I think some annotations may be required in the POJO bean class. If the content type was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then I know that the fields should be annotated `@FormParam`, but I'm not sure what the annotation should be for `application/json` content.

Thanks a lot for your help...
- Ajoy

Comment: The message body parameter should have _no_ annotation at all. If you remove the `@BeanParam`, and you get an error like "No MessageBodreadter for type Wdiget and application/json", then you neen a JSON provider

Comment: Thanks, @peeskillet. That worked. I did not have to do anything else because the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider was found. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, with the exception of some forms annotations, the body parameter does not need any annotations. That is actually how JAX=RS will determine that it *is* the body. So you can only have *one* non-annotated parameter, as you can only have one body. So just change what you have to this (just removing the `@BeanParam`. As long as you have a JSON provider, it should work.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("create")
public Response createWidget(Widget widget) {
```